# Adding int to string

Tags: java

Im triying to make a list which should look like this
Pages = ["Page 1", "Page 2" ... "Page 48"]

and im using this, Is there anything wrong with the following lines?

```
String[] Pages = {};
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < 47; i++) {
        String p = Integer.toString(i+1);
        Pages[i] = ("Page " + p);
    }
```

it keeps giving me a arrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: The `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is caused by the fact that `Pages` is declared to be `{ }`, and therefore has no indexable elements. It is being thrown when evaluating `Pages[i]`, not when doing `"Page " + p`. To correct, try `String[] Pages = new String[47];` :-)

Comment: You said you want a list but you're using an array. Try googling lists in java.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko is correct... do you want a dynamic, growing `List<String>` instead?

Comment: Sorry for not being able to fully explain my question correctly , im coming from python and "[]" is a list there, so i got used to it :/ All answers are great, thanks all, especially dan and veer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164729/adding-int-to-string#comment16280492_12164729),

> The `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is caused by the fact that `Pages` is declared to be `{ }`, and therefore has no indexable elements -- it has a length of `0`.
>
> The exception is being thrown when evaluating `Pages[i]`, not when doing `"Page " + p`. To correct, try instead `String[] Pages = new String[47];` :-)

OR, as Ash mentioned in the comments, do you want a `List<String>` instead?

```
final List<String> pages = new ArrayList<String>(47);
for (int i = 1; i <= 47; ++i) {
  pages.add("Page " + i);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Pages was initialized with length 0. `String[] Pages = new String[47];` will solve your issue.

Comment: You should expand on your answer. How could they solve their issue?

Comment: Why would you clone my answer in the comments?

Comment: @veer while I was writing my answer there was no comment.

Comment: @dan I find that hard to believe given I answered a full minute prior with a longer more in-depth response.

Comment: @veer And why didn't you add your comment as an answer?

Comment: @veer It is the same answer because it is the proper one. I don't know how to demonstrate that I didn't see your comment. Anyway for me, right now, for my answer is saying 14 mins ago and your comment is 13 mins ago.

Comment: @dan nevermind, this is pointless (mine says 15 mins ago on my comment)

Comment: @Baz because I didn't think it had enough substance to be an answer (nor did I think the OP had enough substance to be a question, either)

Comment: @veer Then you should have flagged the question.

Answer (score 3):

A cleaner and better way is to use `Collection`......

Try using a List

```
List<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i=0 ; i<47 ; i++ ){


    aList.add("Page :"+i);

 }
```

A collection will give u huge flexibility over array.........

Comment: Isn't it `Add()` not `add()`?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko no it is `add`.

Comment: Just checking :P. It's a while since I've looked at java.

Comment: Only if clean and better is your priority, I would recommend setting the initial size of the `Collection` if the size is known. This prevents the `Collection` from constantly having to resize as it reaches its item threshold.

In this case though, you'll never notice a performance difference with that small of a `Collection`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your array has not been initialized to 47, instead 0. Try this:

```
String[] Pages = new String[47];
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: In fact, it was initialised, but with length 0, i.e., it's empty.

Comment: What Luke said (with Baz' correction). Arrays in Java can't be sized dynamically, you have to decide on the size when you declare it. You can use ArrayList if you don't know the size beforehand.